# How to format latitude and Longitude labels to show only degrees with suffix without any decimal or minutes?

Tags: qgis, labeling, coordinates, mapping, format

I am setting my latitude and longitude labels in the QGIS map > map grid properties > draw coordinates > format but this only has decimal, decimal with suffix, degree minutes (w and w/o suffix) etc but I only want the degrees with suffix as in 78° E, 65° N but I cant see a way to get to that format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do this by selecting `Decimal with Suffix` for the format and at the bottom of the `Map Grid Properties` select 0 for `Coordinate Precision`.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In your grid properties first make sure to choose EPSG:4326 as CRS, then choose "custom" as coordinate format and click on the expression button next to it:

[image]

Now use this expression:

```sql
abs(@grid_number) ||  '°' || -- concat absolute grid number (without -) with °
if(@grid_number=0,'', -- if grid number is 0, dont use a suffix
    if(
        @grid_axis = 'x', -- determine which grid axis it is
        if(@grid_number<0,'W','E'), -- If grid number is negative and axis is x, use W, else E as suffix
        if(@grid_number<0,'S','N') -- If grid number is negative and axis is y, use S, else N as suffix
    )
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm tempted to revert that edit!